# Рисование гистограммы с рандомными цветами столбцов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, гистограммы

Задача такая: нужно написать программу, которая будет генерировать n-ое количество столбцов (пусть будет 10, как у меня в коде ниже), для каждого столбца рандомно задаётся цвет и высота. Толщина везде одинаковая. По кнопке столбцы выводятся.

Проблемы две: 1) выводятся только отрицательные значения (гистограмма строится ниже оси X) 2) Не знаю, как обновить цвет после того, как прокручивается цикл. В результате все столбцы одинакового цвета.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    Pen coord = new Pen(Color.Black);
    public List<int> massive = new List<int> ();
    public Random rnd = new Random();
    int size;
    int width;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        size = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        width = 700 / 2/ size;
        g.TranslateTransform(50, 213);
        g.DrawLine(coord, 0, -200, 0, 200); //Y axis (ось)
        g.DrawLine(coord, 0, 0, 700, 0); //X axis (ось)


    }

    private List<int> filling (int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            massive.Add(rnd.Next(0, 200));
        }
        return massive;
    }

    private void draw_all (List<int> massive)
    {
        Pen rec = new Pen (Color.Black);
        Random rclr = new Random();

        SolidBrush filler = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256)));
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        g.TranslateTransform(0, 213);
        int x = 0;
        int w = 0;
        Random wrd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10;)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, 1, 30, w);
            g.FillRectangle(filler, rect);
            rclr.Next(256);
            w = wrd.Next (5, 120);
            x = x + 80;
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filling(size);
        draw_all(massive);
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать, в какую сторону копать и в чём ошибка, как лучше организовать код. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вам нужно именно нарисовать или просто гистограмма? Просто можно было взять стандартный Chart и раскрасить как нравится, остальное в нем уже есть и даже больше.

Comment: Именно рисовать :). В противном случае, я бы не мучился и давно бы использовал Chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Вы, конечно, знаете, что на экране ось Y направлена вниз?

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, 200 - w, 30, w);
```

2 -

```
//rclr.Next(256);
filler.Color = Color.FromArgb(rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256));
```

Comment: Оказывается, всё было проще, чем казалось. Не знаю, почему я не подумал об этом. Спасибо большое, одной проблемой меньше! 
P.S. Насчёт осей перепутал, так как спешил :) А как можно начать выводить значения выше оси Х?

Comment: Сделал 0-w вместо 200-w. Выводятся как раз так, как и нужно. В остальном всё так. Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: @nvmqa На здоровье. Успехов!